# Nikon EN-EL15 vs EN-EL15a

Tags: nikon, battery

I have read that EN-EL15 batteries work in cameras that come with EN-EL15a such as the D850.

Is there any difference or reason why to use one over the other? Does it depend on the camera? The EN-EL15 are a bit cheaper where I am and there are a lot more available alternatives (plus I already have 4 of them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nikon updated the design of the original EN-EL15 due to overheating issues. They issued a voluntary recall of some of the manufactured lots of EN-EL15 batteries, and stopped producing the non-"a" versions.

For more information, see Nikon's recall notice, [To users of the EN-EL15 Rechargeable Li-ion Battery](https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/eu/BV_article?articleNo=000006311&sitecode=en_CY&ctry=CY&lang=en_GB).

Comment: I also wasn't sure I can use a "a" version with my D500 but the Nikon page says all these models are cross compatible. Here in Switzerland the "a" version is even cheaper, then if I have to buy a new spare battery I would go for the "a" version.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a scientific opinion, my personal experience is that I have issues when using the non_"A" version of the battery while shooting on High Continuous.  I have found a number of shutter response issues when I am shooting sports and using the non"A" version.  With everything else being the same, I have never had these issues when using the 15a.  Both are Nikon Batteries, but the 15A is much newer. Just a thought when deciding between the two and the little extra for the 15a.

Comment: Which camera(s) are you using?